# Advanced combobox binding from code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

Suppose I have a business object '`obj1`' that has property '`P`'.

Let's also assume that I have a list of business objects: '`List<BussObj> list`' and each BussObj object contains 2 properties: '`A`' and '`B`'.

This list is bound to combobox: `combobox.ItemsSource = list;`.

I would like to specify binding (in C# code) that would bind combobox.SelectedItem.B to my obj.P. How to do it?

I tried something like that but it does not work:

```
Binding bind= new Binding("B");
bind.Source = obj.P;
comboSubject.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, bind);
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

What exactly doesn't work? Is the corresponding item not selected in the `ComboBox`, or is `P` not updated when selection changes? Is the value of `P` in the list that the `ComboBox` is bound to?

You might also try verifying that the type of `obj` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or is a `DependencyObject` with `P` being a `DependencyProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn`t clarify it. I`m using this binding in one way only: after choosing some item in combobox, appriopriate value should be written to `obj.P`. In that scenario no INotifyPropChanged nor DependencyProperty is necessary

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this or if this will help, but you can try using the one way to source binding mode as the default would be TwoWay:

```
Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource
```

Also, I would do it like this, not sure if this helps though:

```
   comboSubject.SetBinding(
       Selector.SelectedItemProperty,
       new Binding { Source = selectedItemSource, Path = "SelectedItem" });
```

See if this does the trick...